# ERROR springsecurity.ReflectionUtils - Your security configuration settings use the old prefix 'grails.plugins.springsecurity'

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.5

I have migrated to grails 2.5.0 from 2.3.7
and i have the dependency on
`compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"`

i replaced all the occurrences of `grails.plugins.springsecurity` with `'grails.plugin.springsecurity` but i am still getting an error as below:

```
Error |
    2015-07-30 17:26:30,191 [main] 
ERROR springsecurity.ReflectionUtils  - Your security configuration settings use the old prefix 'grails.plugins.springsecurity' but must now use 'grails.plugin.springsecurity'
```

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In `Config.groovy` change the line

grails.**plugins**.springsecurity

to 
grails.**plugin**.springsecurity

Comment: lifesaver :grin:

Answer (score 0):

Stopping and starting the app again worked for me.

Could you please do the same and try?

Thanks,
Vamshi

Answer (score 0):

If you have removed all occurrences of grails.plugins.springsecurity, then you may have to check for any DSL style declarations too - like grails { plugins { springsecurity .....